# vuetify simple table. Convert nested object propertied to <td> columns

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify 2.1 and a simple nested table. with the following data structure in my data model:

```
groups:[
  {
      style:"X",
      colours:"colours",
      sizes:"standard",
      marketplaces:[
        {
          markeplace:"UK",
          pricelists:["A","B","C"]
        },
        {
          markeplace:"EU",
          pricelists:["D","E","F"]
        },
        {
          markeplace:"ROW",
          pricelists:["G","H","I"]
        },
      ]
  },
  {
      style:"X",
      colours:"Black/White",
      sizes:"standard",
      marketplaces:[
        {
          markeplace:"UK",
          pricelists:["X","Y","Z"]
        },
        {
          markeplace:"EU",
          pricelists:["P","Q","R"]
        },
        {
          markeplace:"ROW",
          pricelists:["S","T","U"]
        },
      ]
  }
]
```

What I want to achieve is < td > records for:

- style
- colour
- size
- UK.pricelists[0]
- UK.pricelists[1]
- UK.pricelists[2]
- EU.pricelists[0]
- EU.pricelists[1]
- EU.pricelists[2]
- ROW.pricelists[0]
- ROW.pricelists[1]
- ROW.pricelists[2]

```
<v-simple-table
  dense
  calculate-widths
  fixed-header
  height="90vh"
>
  <template v-slot:default>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Style</th>
        <th>Colour Group</th> 
        <th>Size Group</th>
        <th>UK 1</th> 
        <th>UK 2</th> 
        <th>UK 3</th> 
        <th>EU 1</th> 
        <th>EU 2</th> 
        <th>EU 3</th> 
        <th>ROW 1</th> 
        <th>ROW 2</th> 
        <th>ROW 3</th> 
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="group in groups" >
        <td>{{group.style}}</td>
        <td>{{group.colour}}</td>
        <td>{{group.size}}</td>
        <!-- this is where I am struggling... I need the next 9 td records to iterate through two levels of arrays. -->
        <td v-for="mkt in group.marketplaces">{{mkt.pricelists[0]}}<td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </template>
</v-simple-table>
```

for reference I have complete control over the API and the shape of the data object so feel free to suggest an alternative document structure.  Can you native iterate over multiple levels in vuetify simple table - perhaps using array.foreach().
Is there a vue equivalent of react-fragment which acts as outer nesting element but does not actually render anything.  The challenge is that this is within a table row and I need a collection around only some of the cells in the row.
do I move the logic to a method which remaps the pricelists for the passed in group.  In my situation, all groups will have the same marketplaces in the same order and each marketplace will have the same number of price lists so I don't have any issues with sorting or padding the array.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of any other suggestions, I have create a method to remap the data into a single array:

```
methods: {
     remapPricelists(style,colours,sizes){
          /* This should find a single match */
          let group = this.groups.filter(g=>{
               return g.style ==  style 
                 && g.colours == colours
                 && g.sizes == sizes
          });
          let pl =[];
          group[0].pricelists.map(plst =>{
               pl = pl.concat(plst.pricelists);
          });
          return pl;
      }
}
```

DISCLAIMER: I have edited the above code from my live data which has a slightly different format (more outer groups and differently named fields) so E&OE.  In production, I will likely abstract the group fetch to a separate method as I am going to need it in lots of places and will likely strip the outer array to just leave the group object so that I can access the inner data without having to specify the group array-index.